# Change the size of the number input spinner?

Tags: css, html

On a number input it has a spinner which has several css properties but I can't seem to find a way to change the size of the spinner itself. I am talking about `<input type='number'>`. I tried finding something that would change the size but I haven't been able to find anything. The other issue I guess is that every browser on possibly every OS is going to have a potentially different implementation of the spinner itself. When I say spinner I am talking about the highlighted part of this image.
 [image]

I cannot use the JQuery UI spinner because the large app I am developing uses JQuery UI 1.8 which did not include the spinner. Upgrading causes issues.

Comment: I too haven't found how to change the size of the spinner itself. Even if this isn't explicitly configurable, you'd think that it would at least scale automatically (proportional to the input's height, line-height, and/or font-size. As is, it looks ridiculous when you make everything else bigger because the spinner's size stays small.

Answer (score 4):

Not ideal, but try playing around with the CSS transform property:

For example,

```
input[type=number]
{
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

This increases the size of the entire input, but maybe this (in conjunction with setting font-size, line-height, height, width) can produce a desired effect.

Comment: This does work, sort of. But it scales the buttons up using *nearest neighbour* interpolation - not even bilinear! - so it looks awful.

Comment: That's funny. Yeah, you might have size its neighbors, fonts, etc to adjust. Oh well, it was just a hacky idea anyway.

Comment: @Timmmm : If I tried this, I would probably wrap it inside of an inline-block where invisible overflow (from the scaling) is chopped off. You'd basically encapsulate the craziness into something more manageable. I don't expect you to understand what I've just said, but also I don't have time to explain further either.

Comment: I understand you but the whole point of a spinner is that it gives you nice (in theory) buttons easily. If you're just going to hackily hide them you may as well use `<input type="text" pattern="\d+">` and separate buttons, as suggested by @progsource.

Comment: If someone has time to report this as a bug (to each browser that has the problem), post the links here and I'll go there an chime in.

Answer (score 2):

This CSS seems to work in Chrome by replacing the spinners with a static image (of a spinner) and then control the size and position of the image within the element and making it invisible by default until the user hovers over it:

```
* Spin Buttons modified */
input[type="number"].mod::-webkit-outer-spin-button, 
input[type="number"].mod::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #0F0 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAYAAADgkQYQAAAAKUlEQVQYlWNgwAT/sYhhKPiPT+F/LJgEsHv37v+EMGkmkuImoh2NoQAANlcun/q4OoYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) no-repeat center center;
    width: 3em;
    border-left: 1px solid #0f0;
    opacity: 0; /* shows Spin Buttons per default (Chrome >= 39) */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
input[type="number"].mod::-webkit-inner-spin-button:hover,
input[type="number"].mod::-webkit-inner-spin-button:active{
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #0CF;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain ole HTML...

No library or images required.

HTML

```
<!--   Score Control Container -->
<div class = "Score-Control">
  <div class = "Score-Value-Container">
    <div id="RoundScore" class="Score-Value">
      10
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class = "Score-UpDown">
    <div class = "Score-Button-Container">
      <div class = "Score-Button " onclick="IncrementScore();"> 
        &#x25B2;
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "Score-Button-Container">
      <div class = "Score-Button " onclick="DecrementScore();"> 
        &#x25BC;
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Score-Control {
  width: 200px;
}

.Score-Value-Container{ 
  position:relative;
  display: table; 
  overflow: hidden;
  height:80px;
  background-color:#aaa; 
  width:66%; 
  float:left;
  font-size: 44px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center;
}

.Score-Value {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center;
}

.Score-UpDown{
  position:relative;
  height:80px;
  background-color: burlywood; 
  width:34%; 
  float:right;
}

.Score-Button-Container {
  display: table; 
  height: 50%; 
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color:green;
}

.Score-Button {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 27px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function IncrementScore() {
  var RoundScore = document.getElementById("RoundScore").innerHTML;
  if (RoundScore < 10) {
    RoundScore++
    document.getElementById("RoundScore").innerHTML = RoundScore;
  }
}

function DecrementScore() {
  var RoundScore = document.getElementById("RoundScore").innerHTML;
  if (RoundScore > 1) {
    RoundScore--
    document.getElementById("RoundScore").innerHTML = RoundScore;
  }
}
```

[Code in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MisfitGeek/ddf9bL2s/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=ddf9bL2s)

Answer (score 0):

You could make an input field with two buttons for up and down and style them then the way you like.

```
<input type="text" name="something">
<span class="goUp"></span>
<span class="goDown"></span>
```

js:

```
var inputField = $('input[name="something"]');
$('.goUp').click(function() {
    inputField.val(inputField.val() + 1);
});

$('.goDown').click(function() {
    inputField.val(inputField.val() - 1);
});
```

you then should also check, that the input has only numbers inside, so that your +/- 1 really works.

Answer (score 0):

The “size of the spinner” is a vague concept, but the `<input type=number>` element seems to obey at least `width`, `height`, and font property settings. Example:

```html
    <input type=number value=42 min=0 max=99
      style="font: 24pt Courier; width: 3ch; height: 3em">
```

Whether such settings are useful and whether they *should* work is a different issue. It can be argued that the implementation of such elements is expected to be a browser-dependent nice, useable widget suitable for the browsing conditions, rather than something that authors should mess around with. But in practice, the widget is largely affected by CSS settings, and this might be a good thing in practice, e.g. because the input box tends to be too wide by default. (We could expect browsers to set it according to `min` and `max` values, but this just doesn’t happen at present.) The risk is that by setting the width, you might conflict with the implementation. The code above expects the up and down arrows to take a width of one character at most, but this guess might some day be wrong.

Comment: He's talking about the actual up and down buttons. This doesn't change them for me in Chrome.